# Keeping False Conditional From Allowing an Alternation to Match

Tags: .net, regex

The following regular expression matches a sequence of word characters surrounded by single quotes (desired). It also matches an empty pair of single quotes (not desired). **How do I keep this expression from matching empty quotes?**

```
'(\w|(?(bracket)-))+'
```

I'm using .Net's reg ex engine.

### What I've Figured Out

If the named capture group `bracket` isn't present, the `(?(bracket)-)` clause apparently evaluates to nothing, effectively turning the expression into one that matches a quote followed by one or more word characters or nothings followed by another quote. In essence:

```
'(\w|)+'
```

To work around this, the conditional could be modified to include a *no* clause that repeats the `\w` from the first part of the alternation:

```
'(\w|(?(bracket)-|\w))+'
```

However, this introduces repletion, which I'd like to avoid. In this simplistic example, the repetition is tolerable but it won't be in the more complex expression I'm trying to build using this concept.

Comment: Where is the `bracket` group defined at? Or why isn't it defined?

Comment: Good question! It's defined in a larger expression that contains this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this `'(\w|(?(bracket)-|(?!)))+'`

```
 ## Subexpression to define 'bracket' group
 ## up here

 '                     # Quote char
 (                     # (1 start)
      \w                    # word char
   |                      # or,
      (?(bracket)           # Conditional: Did 'bracket' group match something?
           -                     # Yes, match '-'
        |                      # or,  
           (?!)                  # No, fail this part
      )
 )+                    # (1 end)
 '                     # Quote char
```

For example `(?<bracket>\[)?'(\w|(?(bracket)-|(?!)))+'`

would match `['st-art'` and `['-'`
but not `='st-art'` nor `='-'`
and never `''` empty quotes

Comment: In other terms, when a `\w` is found, the conditional will not be reached.

Comment: Ah! That's what I needed--an empty zero-width negative look-ahead [`(?!)']. Thank you!